# Unable to connect Hive with Zookeeper Service Discovery mode via JDBC

Tags: jdbc, hive, apache-zookeeper

I am creating a jdbc connection to hive using javax.sql.DataSource and passing zookeeper service discovery (obtained from Ambari) string to Hive .

```
Zookeeper Hive URL : jdbc:hive2://localhost:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice
```

If I make direct jdbc connection with HiveServer host and port then connection work properly but it fails with zookeeper string.

After that I tested zookeeper string with beeline and I worked fine.

Below is exception when connection is made.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: Unable to read HiveServer2 uri from ZooKeeper
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:205)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:710)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:644)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:466)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:85)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.kerberos.KerberosUtil.getConnectionWithOrWithoutKerberos(KerberosUtil.java:60)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.hive.service.RefreshableDataSource.getConnectionForValidation(RefreshableDataSource.java:113)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.hive.service.RefreshableDataSource.testAndRefreshIfInvalid(RefreshableDataSource.java:133)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.hive.service.RefreshableDataSource.getConnection(RefreshableDataSource.java:145)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.kerberos.KerberosUtil.getConnectionWithOrWithoutKerberos(KerberosUtil.java:60)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.schema.DBSchemaParser.listCatalogs(DBSchemaParser.java:80)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientException: Unable to read HiveServer2 uri from ZooKeeper
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.getNextServerUriFromZooKeeper(ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.java:86)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.updateConnParamsFromZooKeeper(Utils.java:506)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:203)
    ... 136 more
Caused by: org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientException: Tried all existing HiveServer2 uris from ZooKeeper.
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.getNextServerUriFromZooKeeper(ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.java:73)
    ... 138 more
```

Did anyone encounter this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending my 2 days , i figured out problem . I have hive 0.14 dependency in my code where this problem is occurring. To fix i updated below two hive maven dependencies..

Hive Services - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-service/1.2.1000.2.4.2.10-1

Hive JDBC - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/1.2.1000.2.4.2.10-1